# Custom List Form Will Not Deploy

Tags: development, visual-studio, deployment

A demo List Form using Visual Studio 2010 to test and experiment with a few things.  Nothing at all was added inside the project.  Functionality, etc, will be added later, but at this point it was just to test to see if it worked.  The project was created the standard way by adding a List Definition with a list instance to an Empty SharePoint Project (as a farm solution).  After that, it was just deployed (right-click the project and "Deploy") to see if it would be seen in the SharePoint site.

After deploying, the custom list could not be found in the SharePoint site itself or in SharePoint Designer.  Checking the output tab in Visual Studio showed the information below.

Any help and advice would be greatly appreciated!

Quick note:  I'm relatively new to SharePoint development and have only been doing it for a few months.  Please go easy on me.

```
------ Build started: Project: SPCustomListFormDemo, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
  SPCustomListFormDemo -> E:\Docs\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SPCustomListFormDemo\SPCustomListFormDemo\bin\Debug\SPCustomListFormDemo.dll
  Successfully created package at: E:\Docs\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SPCustomListFormDemo\SPCustomListFormDemo\bin\Debug\SPCustomListFormDemo.wsp
------ Deploy started: Project: SPCustomListFormDemo, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
Active Deployment Configuration: Default
Run Pre-Deployment Command:
  Skipping deployment step because a pre-deployment command is not specified.
Recycle IIS Application Pool:
  Skipping application pool recycle because no matching package on the server was found.
Retract Solution:
  Skipping package retraction because no matching package on the server was found.
Add Solution:
  Adding solution 'SPCustomListFormDemo.wsp'...
  Deploying solution 'SPCustomListFormDemo.wsp'...
Activate Features:
  Activating feature 'Feature1' ...
Run Post-Deployment Command:
  Skipping deployment step because a post-deployment command is not specified.
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue that the list doesn't show up could be related to multiple things. Start off with checking the Package (Package.package within VS solution) and make sure that feature is included in the Package. If so, proceed with checking the List Instance and List Definition within the Feature.

With VS 2010, you've to be very careful while creating Lists and Libraries using Module File provisioning method. As mentioned by Stephen, go ahead and download VS2012 which would make your development/customization a lot simpler. All your SP2010 solution(s) should work with VS2012. If everything looks good, create a new List and see if that shows up. I would suggest to get a working solution (there are many in codeplex, http://spcustomlistformdemo.codeplex.com) then compare it against your solution.

For setting up a custom form, I'll recommend you read these two articles:

http://blog.karstein-consulting.com/2010/12/29/walkthrough-create-custom-sharepoint-2010-list-form-for-deployment-in-a-visual-studio-2010-project/

http://www.intrateam.com/gb/blogpost/sharepoint-2013-list-custom-form (This article is for SP2013 but same approach works for SP2010)

Good Luck,
Abhi

Answer (score 0):

I always found creating a list when deploying a solution via VS2010 overly complicated, having to create a list, list instance and content type etc.

VS2012 makes this a much simpler process. However if your stuck using VS2010 the following article takes you through the process.

[Exercise 1: Creating Lists with Visual Studio 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365trainingcourse_lab_2_2_topic3.aspx)

Comment: I am working with SharePoint Server 2010 along with VS2010.  If I could get VS2012, would it also work with SP2010?

Comment: Yes you can build everything in VS2012 and deploy to SP2010 etc.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on here. I tried everything in that link exactly as is (except that I generated new GUIDs instead of using the ones shown for ProductID and ProductDescription). Even though the output from VS2010 said it's deployed and activated, nothing shows up in SharePoint. (Sometimes I wonder if Microsoft's technologies just suddenly malfunction when I'm around.)

Comment: Have you had a look at the solution gallery to ensure its there and activated? Sounds like it will be one of those daft things rather than you doing anything wrong...

Comment: It's in the Solutions Gallery and it's activated.

Comment: Also check your site collection features and see if its listed there...

Comment: It was listed in Site Collection Features, but not activited.  I activated it, but still couldn't see it anywhere else like in Lists and Libraries in SPD or All Site Content.

Comment: Now that its activated...when you try and add a list from the gallery your list should be listed...

Comment: Listed where?  I don't see it anywhere that I can add it or use it!  It's in central admin, site collection features and solutions gallery but I can't do anything with it from those places other than deactivate and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a scope issue. You stated yourself that this is "*as a farm solution*". You need to go into Central Administrator, instead of "*SharePoint site itself or in SharePoint Designer*", and look at your installed farm solutions there. Also you may want to consider looking at the following link. It details the steps for a proper installation and deployment of farm solutions.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa544500(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: Went to Central Admin > System Settings > Manage farm solutions and say it in the saying it's Globally Deployed.

Comment: I followed the steps you outlined exactly and it worked fine for me. I created an Empty SharePoint 2010 project in Visual Studio. I right-clicked on the project and Added a List Definition. I opted for it to create the List Instance through the wizard.

I then deployed the project the same way you described. Right-clicked the project and deployed. It put the list on my SharePoint site as follows: http://<yourservergoeshere>/Lists/SharePointProject1-ListInstance1/AllItems.aspx